# Backload thumbnails generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, thumbnails, backload

I use Backload as backend for plupload. Is there any way to disable automatic thumbnails generation in backload? I didn't find a notice about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in official documentation. Maybe it would be useful to someone.
Set the path attribute of the thumbnails configuration element to an empty string: `<thumbnails path="" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Setting path to empty string is not sufficient for backload version 2.2.2. Instead `<thumbnails  ... >` has a `store` attribute. So you need to put this into configuration:
`<thumbnails store="false" />`